# No need to press, when default is true (auto loop)

Tags: c#

```
string tastetryk;

ConsoleKeyInfo tast;
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
Console.Clear();
do
{

     Console.WriteLine("Menu");
     Console.WriteLine(" ");
     Console.WriteLine("Tryk en tast for at vælge funktion");
     Console.WriteLine(" ");
     Console.WriteLine("I - Beregn strøm");
     Console.WriteLine("U - Spænding");
     Console.WriteLine("R - Modstand");
     Console.WriteLine(" ");
     Console.WriteLine("(Esc) for at slutte ");

     tast = Console.ReadKey();
     tastetryk = tast.Key.ToString();
     Console.Clear();

     switch(tastetryk)
     {
         case "I":
             Console.WriteLine("du har tastet I");
             Console.Write("Tast Q for at komme tilbage");
             tast = Console.ReadKey();
             break;

         case "U":
             Console.WriteLine("du har tastet U");
             Console.Write("Tast Q for at komme tilbage");
             tast = Console.ReadKey();
             break;

         case "R":
             Console.WriteLine("du har tastet R");
             Console.Write("Tast Q for at komme tilbage");
             tast = Console.ReadKey();
             break;

         default:
             Console.WriteLine("forkert tast");
             Thread.Sleep(1000);
             Console.Clear(); 
             break;
    }                
}
while (tast.Key == ConsoleKey.Q);
```

I made this code for a Menu, when i press I, U or R, one of the case will come true, when you press Q it will return to main menu. My problem is when default is true, i want it to loop to main menu without any need to press Q, I tried with tast = Consolekey.Q

Sorry for my really bad english

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, you cannot `break` from the loop since the `break` breaks from the `switch` statement, as you've surely noticed.

Two simple solutions :

First, add a boolean flag indicating you should exit the loop, adding a new condition in the `while` statement.

```
bool bExit = false;

do
{
    switch 
    {
        /*
        code here
        */
        default:
            bExit = true;
            //etc.
    }
}
while(tast.Key == ConsoleKey.Q || !bExit)
```

Now, I know thid could be considered pure evil but... have you considered using a `goto`?

```
do
{
    switch 
    {
         /*
         code here
         */
         default:
            goto outOfLoop;
    }
}
while(tast.Key == ConsoleKey.Q)

outOfLoop:

// etc.
```

I believe the second solution is actually cleaner but people could react violently to `goto` statements.

Comment: Yeah i was about to use goto, but our teacher told us never to use it... :)

Comment: That's the general sentiment and, if used improperly, it can generate code that is very difficult to maintain. On the other hand, I'm not too fond of magical exit conditions either. Normally I'd tell you to use your best judgment... but if this homework then listen to your teacher and use the first solution instead! ;)